# Log files limit

Tags: file-handling

I'm working on simple project to gather sensor data and save them in .txt file in SD-card. The code I have looked on internet is just for saving 100 files but lets say if I want to save more than that. Maybe 1000 or 10K then how can we modify the code..
This is the code..

```
    char filename[] = "IMULog00.txt";
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
      filename[6] = i / 10 + '0';
      filename[7] = i % 10 + '0';
      if (! SD.exists(filename))
      {
        logfile = SD.open(filename, FILE_WRITE);
        break;  // leave the loop!
       }
     }
     if (! logfile)
     {
      Serial.println("Error: Log file could not created");
      }
```

I tried to change it for 1000 files but It is giving error. I know there is something wrong with the values but couldn't figure out. Kindly point my mistake and if there is some generic code or loop to make .txt files more than 10k or 100k would be alot better.

**My edit..Not working**

```
char filename[] = "IMULog000.txt";
for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
  filename[6] = i / 100 + '0';
  filename[7] = i / 10 + '0';
  filename[8] = i % 10 + '0';
  if (! SD.exists(filename))
  {
    logfile = SD.open(filename, FILE_WRITE);
    break;  // leave the loop!
   }
  }
  if (! logfile)
  {
    Serial.println("Error: Log file could not created");
   }
```

Comment: Can you please add the error as well?

Comment: Firstly, it was going till 99 and then re-writing 99 file and again and again and with the above modification, when it crosses 99 the next file should be 100,101,102,....

Instead I'm getting these kinda files.

**IMULG1:1.txt**
**IMULG1:2.txt**
**IMULG1:3.txt**

Comment: Can not really pin point the issue, however try changing `uint8_t` to `uint16_t` and then printing value of `filename` before `if (! SD.exists(filename))`.

Comment: I tried changing to uint16_t but the results are same. when counter value i.e. **"i"** in loop increases above 99 it print 100,101,102 as **1:0, 1:1,1:2** so on till **109** and on **110 when 2nd digit is 1, it simply does not create txt file**. Tried different values but the counter above 99 is not making files correctly..